# Can I evaluate $\sum_n^\infty x^{n^2}y^n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ such that their product is $0<xy<1$.

Is their anything I can say about the following sum?
$$S(x,y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n^2}y^n$$

Under what condition does this sum converges? Intuitively I would say that $0<\sqrt{x}y<1$ is required.

Of course, if there was a single power of $n$ I would have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n}y^n=1/(1-xy)$. Unfortunately I am stuck with this sum and I was wondering if this is the end of the road or if it is possible to go one step further...

Comment: Use root test to find condition for convergence.

Comment: Your $0<\sqrt{x}y<1$ is not going to work: try $x=2$ and $y=\frac1{16}$ as an example which would result in $x^{n^2}y^n$ increasing with $n$ for $n>3$